# Custom fact with home directorys as domains for puppet

Tags: bash, puppet, theforeman, facter

I'm trying to generate a custom *fact* called *domains*. 
the idea is to list all the directories within `/home` but remove some default directory's such as `centos`, `ec2-user`, `myadmin`.

I'm using bash as I don't know ruby. so far my script outputs the list into a txt file which it then cats the answer for factors. but it is treated as one long answer and not multiple like an array?

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -m /home/ | sed -e 's/, /,/g' | tr -d '\n' > /tmp/domains.txt  
cat /tmp/domains.txt | awk '{gsub("it_support,", "");print}'| awk  '{gsub("ec2-user,", "");print}'| awk '{gsub("myadmin,", "");print}'| awk  '{gsub("nginx", "");print}'| awk '{gsub("lost+found,", "");print}' >  /tmp/domains1.txt
echo "domains={$(cat /tmp/domains1.txt)}"

exit
```

Foremans sees my domains as

```
facts.domains = "{domain1,domain2,domain3,domain4,lost+found,}"
```

I also need to remove `lost+found,` some how.

Any help or advice would be appreciated

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not familiar with ruby, but I have an idea for some workaround:

Please look at the following example about [returning an array of network interfaces](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.0/fact_overview.html#example-returning-an-array-of-network-interfaces). Now to create *domain_array* fact use the following code:

```
Facter.add(:domain_array) do
  setcode do
  domains = Facter.value(:domains)
  domain_array = domains.split(',')
  domain_array
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a parser function to do this. Parser functions go inside:

```
 modules/<modulename>/lib/puppet/parser/functions/getdomain.rb
```

Note: Parser function will compile only in the puppet master. See below for a custom fact that will run on the agent.

`getdomain.rb` can contain something like the following for your purpose:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:getdomain, :type => :rvalue) do |args|

    dnames=Array.new
    Dir.foreach("/home/") do |d|
      # Avoid listing directories starts with . or ..
      if !d.start_with?('.') then
        # You can put more names inside the [...] that you want to avoid
        dnames.push(d) unless ['lost+found','centos'].include?(d)
      end
    end

    domainlist=dnames.join(',')
    return domainlist
 end
end
```

You can call it from a manifest and assign to a variable:

```
$myhomedomains=getdomain()
```

`$myhomedomains` should return something similar to this : `user1,user2,user3`

```
  .......
```

For a custom fact with similar code. You can put it in :

```
 modules/<modulename>/lib/facter/getdomain.rb
```

Content of `getdomain.rb` :

```
Facter.add(:getdomain) do
  setcode do
    dnames=Array.new
    Dir.foreach("/home/") do |d|
      # Avoid listing directories starts with . or ..
      if !d.start_with?('.') then
        # You can put more names inside the [...] that you want to avoid
        dnames.push(d) unless ['lost+found','centos'].include?(d)
      end
    end
    getdomain=dnames.join(',')
    getdomain
  end
end
```

You can call the `getdomain` fact in any manifest, for example, calling it from the same module's `init.pp` :

```
 notify { "$::getdomain" : }
```

will result in something similar :

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Testmodule/Notify[user1,user2,user3]
```

Comment: This will run on the puppet master, is that what @Kevin is asking for?